# Get data from complex JSON

Tags: php, json

i have a json like this:

> [{"name":"manager","value":["localhost.localdomain"]},{"name":"isManageIp","value":["True"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.ip_address","value":["10.10.10.10"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.production_state","value":["1000"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.priority","value":["3"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.location","value":["London"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.device_class","value":["/Ping"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.groups","value":["/CORE"]}]

and I would like to extract this data:

- 10.10.10.10 from value when name is zenoss.device.ip_address
- 1000 from value when name is zenoss.device.production_state
- London from value when name is zenoss.device.location
- /CORE from value when name is zenoss.device.groups

I tried to reiterate the json in this way:

```
$alarm = json_decode([{"name":"manager","value":["localhost.localdomain"]},{"name":"isManageIp","value":["True"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.ip_address","value":["10.10.10.10"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.production_state","value":["1000"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.priority","value":["3"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.location","value":["London"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.device_class","value":["/Ping"]},{"name":"zenoss.device.groups","value":["/CORE"]}]);
foreach($alarm as $key => $val) {
    echo "KEY IS: $key<br/>";
    foreach($val as $key2 => $val2) {
        echo "KEY2 IS: $key2<br/>";
        foreach($val2 as $key3 => $val3) {
            echo "KEY3 IS: $key3<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

but at some point I get an error returned
it is possible that I have taken the wrong approach
Could you help me please
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what you wanted to do with the extracted data, so right now I'm just doing an echo

```
foreach ($alarm as $val) {
    switch ($val->name) {
        case 'zenoss.device.ip_address':
                echo "IP: ".$val->value[0]."\n";
            break;
        case 'zenoss.device.production_state':
                echo "State: ".$val->value[0]."\n";
            break;
        case 'zenoss.device.location':
                echo "Location: ".$val->value[0]."\n";
            break;
        case 'zenoss.device.groups':
                echo "Groups: ".$val->value[0]."\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

Basically, since you already know the `name` of the `values` you want to extract, you can simply use `switch` to differentiate among the `names`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. I was really confused!!!!!!